# How to make `groupBy` with native javascript

Tags: javascript, collections, ecmascript-6, group-by, lodash

How to achieve `groupBy` with native javascript?

【Definition of `groupBy`】
Creates an object composed of keys generated from the results of running each element of collection thru iteratee. The order of grouped values is determined by the order they occur in collection. The corresponding value of each key is an array of elements responsible for generating the key. The iteratee is invoked with one argument: (value).

【Expect Output】

`groupBy([6.1, 4.2, 6.3], Math.floor);
// => { '4': [4.2], '6': [6.1, 6.3] }`


`groupBy(['one', 'two', 'three'], 'length');
// => { '3': ['one', 'two'], '5': ['three'] }`

Comment: So where is the problem?

Comment: @ Sirko I want to make groupBy with native javascript, not come from lodash

Comment: Without writing the exact code, I think this needs at most 10lines of code: a loop, an `if` and some assignments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with an object to collect the items. The key is created by applying the iteratee to the item.

The iteratee can be a string or a function, so we need to check the type, and if it's a string create function that extracts the property from the item.

The collection can be an array or an object, and we can use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get an array.

```js
const groupBy = (collection, iteratee = (x) => x) => {
  const it = typeof iteratee === 'function' ? 
    iteratee : ({ [iteratee]: prop }) => prop;

  const array = Array.isArray(collection) ? collection : Object.values(collection);

  return array.reduce((r, e) => {
    const k = it(e);
    
    r[k] = r[k] || [];
    
    r[k].push(e);
    
    return r;
  }, {});
};

console.log(groupBy([6.1, 4.2, 6.3], Math.floor)); // => { '4': [4.2], '6': [6.1, 6.3] }
 
console.log(groupBy(['one', 'two', 'three'], 'length')); // => { '3': ['one', 'two'], '5': ['three'] }

console.log(groupBy({ a: 6.1, b: 4.2, c: 6.3 }, Math.floor)); // => { '4': [4.2], '6': [6.1, 6.3] }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` and expose a **generic *group-by-key* function**.

```
function groupBy(arr, groupByKeyFn )
{
   return arr.reduce( (acc, c) => {
       var key = groupByKeyFn(c);
       acc[key] = acc[key] || [];
       acc[key].push(c)
       return acc;
   }, [])
}
```

Now you can use this function as

```
var arr1 = [6.1, 4.2, 6.3];
var arr2 = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

console.log( groupBy(arr1, s => Math.floor(s) ) );
console.log( groupBy(arr2, s => s.length ) );
```

**Demo**

```js
function groupBy(arr, groupByKeyFn) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, c) => {
    var key = groupByKeyFn(c);
    acc[key] = acc[key] || [];
    acc[key].push(c)
    return acc;
  }, {})
}

var arr1 = [6.1, 4.2, 6.3];
var arr2 = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

console.log( groupBy(arr1, s => Math.floor(s) ) );
console.log( groupBy(arr2, s => s.length ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

The modern version of lodash's groupby in "native" js looks like this.

```
const groupBy = (xs, key) => {
  return xs.reduce((rv, x) => {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
};
```

works exactly like lodash itself.